# python-pptx How to set page top margin to 0

Tags: python, layout, powerpoint, python-pptx

I need to place text at the very top of the PPTX page.
There is always a 3/8 top margin.  The code below sets fields to zero but the text start 3/8 inches from the top.

Library: python-pptx 0.6.18

```
ppt = Presentation()

ppt.slide_width = Inches(8.5)

ppt.slide_height = Inches(11)

left = top = Inches(0.0)

width = height = Inches(3.0)

txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(left, top, width, height)   

//# creating textFrames 
//# https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html

tf = txBox.text_frame 

tf.word_wrap = False

tf.margin_top = Inches(0.0)     

tf.margin_bottom = Inches(0.0)

tf.margin_left = Inches(0.0)

tf.margin_right = Inches(0.0)   
                                
tf.vertical_anchor = MSO_ANCHOR.TOP                                        

p = tf.add_paragraph()  
p.alignment = PP_ALIGN.LEFT
```

Thx for help.

Comment: What is the value of topI? If > 0, that'd be at least part of the problem. And is the 3/8" margin appearing on the slide when viewed on screen or when you print it out?  If the latter, you need to change the print settings (NOT fit to page)

Comment: The correct code is: txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(left, top, width, height) .  From the example above, left = top = Inches(0.0)   I also set the  left =  top = Inches(0.1).  In both cases, the text correctly moved to the left page side. but there was always 3/8" text at the top of the page.   The top 3/8" margin appears when viewing.   I went into PowerPoint directly manually entering these same settings and viewed correctly - the text correctly did not have the 3/8" top margin.

Comment: Thanks. VBA guy here, not familiar with the left = top = syntax here. That assigns the same value to both left and top, then?  Makes sense. And the fact that it works for left but not top pretty much leaves a glitch in Inches out of the question. Another thought: does the 3/8" margin appear when you view the presentation in slide show view (ie, press F5)? It would be possible to have an image or background rectangle on the slide extend above the actual slide; in normal view, it'd look as though the top of the slide were the top of the image, though the slide's actually smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to set the margin to 0 doing this:

```
txBox.text_frame.margin_top = pptx.util.Inches(0)
txBox.text_frame.margin_bottom = pptx.util.Inches(0)
```

But it doesn't seem to change anything, there is still some margin on top and bottom. You can instead change the top value to a negative to put text at the very top of the page:

```
ppt = Presentation()

ppt.slide_width = Inches(8.5)

ppt.slide_height = Inches(11)

left = Inches(0.0)
top = Inches(-0.375)

width = height = Inches(3.0)

txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(left, top, width, height)
```

This will force the top (y value) of the box to be moved higher than just 0 can do.